# Calculating probability that the first success is a multiple of $3$

Tags: probability

A biased coin ($P(\text{Heads}) = 0.7$) is flipped. If you get the first tails on the $k$th flip, the probability that k is an integer multiple of $3$ can
be expressed as a reduced fraction $\frac{a}b$. How can I calculate this probability.

Comment: I'd do all three at once.  That is, I'd let $p_0$ be the probability that it comes on a multiple of $3$.  And $p_1$ is the probability that it comes on a turn of the form $3k+1$, and $p_2$ corresponds to $3k+2$.  Now look what happens over the first three tosses.

Comment: The probability that k is a multiple of 3 will then always 1/3. Is that correct?

Comment: Why would you think that?

Comment: There is a $.3$ chance that you win on the very first try.  Then there is a $\left(.7\right)^3\times .3=.1029$ chance you win on the second.  Thus $p_0>.3+.1029>.4$

Comment: Note:  it's not necessary to compute all three probabilities though I like the completeness of it.  You can get $p_0$ via geometric series, noting that the winning paths are those of the form $(TTT)^{3k}H$ and those each have probability $\left(.7\right)^{3k}\times .3$

Comment: So we need to consider that k is a multiple of 3. So if we get tails on the first trial, we need to calculate that 1 is a multiple of 3. How can that be expressed in terms of probability? I'm having difficulty in forming an intuition for the problem itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wrote down the wrong one.  (I was computing $p_1$).  To get $p_0$ the winning paths are $\left(.7\right)^{3k}\times \left(.7\right)^2\times .3$.

Comment: To be sure, I was (incorrectly) working with $p_1$ the whole time,  In truth $p_0<\frac 13$.  Quite a bit less. It's $p_1$ that exceeds $.4$.